# Can you create a Wall of Fire in midair?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, targeting, wall

In 4E and 5E there seems to be the requirement of a Wall of Fire to be resting on a solid surface. But in 3.5 I did not find such a rule. So: can you create a Wall of Fire in midair?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142432/8610)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes

There's nothing in the 3.5 rules to prevent you from placing a *wall of fire* in midair. Nothing in the spell description, or the specific rules for Evocation spells, or the general rules of magic requires that you place a a *wall of fire* on a solid surface.

Some other *wall* spells have the specific requirement to anchor to a surface, but *wall of fire* doesn't.

Interestingly, in another [very good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142432/does-the-prismatic-wall-need-to-be-on-the-ground) regarding *prismatic wall* in the Pathfinder ruleset, Hey I Can Chan notes that objects summoned with Conjuration spells cannot appear in open air, and this rule also appears in D&D 3.5. Since *wall of fire* is Evocation, this limitation doesn't apply.

Comment: Unlike a conjured object (wall of whale?), walls of fire probably do not fall, so the rule is less necessary.